# How to constrain a type to only take instances of a typeclass as argument

Tags: lean

I'm just starting with Lean (and in-depth Functional Programming / Theorem Solving) so my vocabulary might be wrong.

https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/examples/bintree.lean.html is an example of a binary tree.

**How would I extend the binary tree to not take `Nat` as keys, and instead anything that offers a `lesser` function?**

In general, I would like to construct trees with different comparison functions. E.g. for strings I'd like to be able to define a tree that is lexicographically ordered and one that is ordered by string length.

I found how to define a typeclass:

```
class comparable (α : Type _) := (is_lesser: α → α → Bool)
```

And I can have 2 instances for string

```
instance lex_str : comparable String where
  is_lesser x y := x < y

instance len_str : comparable String where
  is_lesser x y := x.length < y.length
```

Now what I'd like to do is define a Tree type:

```
inductive Tree (β : Type v) (d : comparable v) where
| leaf
| node (left : Tree β) (key : d) (value : β) (right : Tree β)
deriving Repr
```

But `d` is not a type.

---

I know that could write

```
inductive Tree (β : Type v) (d : x → x → Bool) where
| leaf
| node (left : Tree β d) (key : x) (value : β) (right : Tree β d)
```

but wouldn't that allow different comparison functions at each node in a tree?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed version:

```
inductive Tree (α : Type u) (β : Type v) [comparable α] where
| leaf
| node (left : Tree α β) (key : α) (value : β) (right : Tree α β)
deriving Repr
```

This includes the following changes:

- The type of `key` should be `α`, not `d`. The keys are the elements of the type `α`, which has a comparable instance. They are not actually comparator functions themselves.
- The comparable instance should be `d : comparable α`, not `d : comparable v`. `v` is a universe level and not a type; you want the elements of `α` to be comparable so that's why you need to pass evidence of `comparable α` (that is to say, a comparator function which operates on elements of type `α`).

(If you are wondering why this didn't give an error saying `v` was not defined, lean interpreted `v` as an implicit variable of type `Type _`. This can be convenient but also hide typos and other errors as in this case. The feature is known as auto-implicits and if you dislike this behavior you can turn it off with `set_option autoImplicit false`, or put `moreLeanArgs := #["-DautoImplicit=false"]` to turn it off project-wide.)

- The brackets around the instance were changed from `(d : comparable α)` to `[d : comparable α]`. You almost always want to use variables of `class` type in brackets, which means that the argument will not be passed explicitly and will be inferred by typeclass inference, making use of those `instance` declarations you made.
- `Tree` now takes `α` explicitly and `d` implicitly, so references to it in the definition are now written `Tree α β` instead of just `Tree β`.
- Because `d` is unused by name (as is common for typeclass instances), we can omit the name and just write `[comparable α]` instead of `[d : comparable α]`.

---

> I know that could write
>
> ```
> inductive Tree (β : Type v) (d : x → x → Bool) where
> | leaf
> | node (left : Tree β d) (key : x) (value : β) (right : Tree β d)
> ```
>
> but wouldn't that allow different comparison functions at each node in a tree?

No. This version is more or less equivalent to the one I just gave above (except that you used `x` for the type name instead of `α`), and it is storing one element of type `x` at each node of the tree. The comparison function is a parameter of the type, and as such it is not stored in the tree at all. In fact, since the instance is not required to define the tree structure you should also consider just omitting it entirely as in:

```
inductive Tree (α : Type u) (β : Type v) where
| leaf
| node (left : Tree α β) (key : α) (value : β) (right : Tree α β)
deriving Repr
```

and instead ask for the `[comparable α]` instance only on the operations that need it, such as `insert`. ABI-wise, what this does (either way) is to pass the comparator function as an argument to all the operations, but not to the constructors. You can't extract the comparator function from the tree, but because it is in the type you can't even write a function manipulating trees that doesn't take the comparator as an argument (or is specialized to a type with a known comparator), so this isn't an issue.